# Static assertions about the size of a template struct

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof, static-assert

I need to make sure a template struct is exactly the size of its members. `static_assert` seems to be the tool of choice here. However, I cannot use a `static_assert` inside the struct itself, because the size is not yet known there. Here is what I would like to have:

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
struct foo {
    T1 v1;
    T2 v2;
    // Doesn't compile, invalid application of sizeof to incomplete type
    static_assert(sizeof(foo<T1,T2>)==sizeof(T1)+sizeof(T2),"Struct size invalid");
};
```

This doesn't work. So how to do it? I don't want to burden people that instantiate the template to check themselves in each instantiation. The check should be fully automatic whenever the struct is instantiated.

Comment: Why not putting the `static_assert` statement e.g. into a constructor function?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖi If the structure is supposed to be a POD type, it can't be the default constructor though. And a `default` default constructor needs to be added.

Answer (score 15):

Rename `foo` to `foo_t`.

```
template<class A, class B>
struct foo_helper {
  using type=foo_t<A,B>;
  static_assert(sizeof(A)+sizeof(B) == sizeof(type), "ouch");
};
template<class A, class B>
using foo=typename foo_helper<A,B>::type;
```

Note that using `foo` instead of `foo_t` blocks deduction in some cases, so this technique is not perfect.

Comment: Which are the cases where deduction is blocked?

Comment: I came up with the same solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779120/work-around-incomplete-type-in-static-assert

Comment: @gio `template<class A, class B> void deduction_no_worky( foo<A,B> const&){}` then `foo<int,char> bob; deduction_no_worky(bob);`  Use `foo_t` directly and it works.

Comment: Thanks, that's crazy... `std::is_same<foo, foo_t>` returns true and yet deduction doesn't work.

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal Yes, the `::type` stuff means this is a non-deduced context.  For deduction to work it would have to be able to invert an arbitrary turing-complete process (in the general case), so the C++ standard instead places a bright line.

Answer (score 10):

You may add a layer:

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
struct bar {
    T1 v1;
    T2 v2;
};

template<typename T1,typename T2>
struct foo : bar<T1, T2> {
    static_assert(sizeof(bar<T1, T2>) == sizeof(T1) + sizeof(T2), "Struct size invalid");
};
```

Comment: Is it not technically possible for `foo` itself to add some [unused] bytes, voiding the result of the assertion? Yakk's idea of a `type` member solves that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed, except if `bar<T1, T2>` has standard layout.

Answer (score 7):

Place the static assertion in a member function.

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
struct foo {
    T1 v1;
    T2 v2;

 static auto assertion()
 {
    static_assert(sizeof(foo<T1,T2>)==sizeof(T1)+sizeof(T2),"Struct size invalid");
 }
};
```

This works because the contents of member functions are not compiled until the class has a complete definition.

There is no need to call the function.

Comment: I am afraid, but your answer doesn't work. At least with my compiler (usual ubuntu gcc). I tried inserting a false assert into the method (I inserted the condition and another static_assert with the negated condition, so one of both must be false) and no assertion triggered.

Comment: _"`[C++14: 14.7.1/1]:`_ [..] _**The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions**, default arguments, or exception-specifications **of the class member functions**, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members and member templates;_ [..] _"_

Comment: _"`[C++14: 14.7.1/2]:` Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly
specialized, **the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist**;_ [..] _"_

Comment: So, yes, you'd have to call it.

Comment: However, [it works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97add29c8610d888) lol wtf

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this looks like a cue for a new "who's compiler is wrong" question :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit its because your assert not depedent on template types. it's allowed to both fire and not assertion

Comment: replace it with something like sizeof(A) == sizeof(A) + 1 and it will not fire

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8056aa60c96ea0d0 (as far as I understand it's still allowed to fire but compiler wouldn't know that)

Comment: @RiaD: Hm. Okay but how does that tally with 14.7.1/1 cited above

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The rules about template functions "must have a valid instantiation" (if we presume members of template classes are template functions in this context) would make the `static_assert(false, "hello")` be ill-formed, no diagnostic **required**.  So both compilers would be correct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `static_assert(false, "!");` will basically always trigger everywhere, since it's non-dependent and it can. Which is annoying, since you have to write `template <class T> struct always_false : std::_false_type { }; static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "!");`. Sigh.

Comment: @Barry Is the legality of a `static_assert` is anywhere dependent on it being in a dependent context in the standard?  I suspect your hack is making an ill formed program with no diagnostic required rather than actually creating a truely "only static assert when instantiated and always false" function.  But that section of the standard needs clarification (is a non-template function of a template class a template function with regards to the clause in question, or not?)

Comment: @Yakk ¯\_(ツ)_/¯