# Work around incomplete type in static assert

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, static-assert

Is there a way to static_assert inside a class when the expression depends on the class type itself? Maybe delay the evaluation until the type is complete or after template instantiation?

Example code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Test {
   T x = 0; // make non-trivial
   static_assert(std::is_trivial<Test<T>>::value, "");
};

int main() {
    // would like static assert failure, instead get 'incomplete type' error
    Test<int> test1;
    Test<float> test2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this specific case you could put the logic in `TestImpl` and have `Test` inherit from it (with inherited constructors & co.) and have the `static_assert` in it working over `TestImpl`. But of course it isn't a general solution.

Comment: Sounds pretty good, but why you say it wouldn't be a general solution?

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking about some corner cases where it wouldn't work correctly, but I can no longer see them. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a helper class and a type alias for indirection. I believe this has no drawbacks.

```
template<typename T>
struct TestImpl {
    T x = 0; // make non-trivial
};

template<typename T>
struct TestHelper {
    using type = TestImpl<T>;
    static_assert(std::is_trivial<type>::value, "");
};

template<typename T>
using Test = typename TestHelper<T>::type;
```

**edit:** Alternatively TestHelper can be moved into TestImpl:

```
template<typename T>
struct TestImpl {
    T x = 0; // make non-trivial

    struct Helper {
        using type = TestImpl;
        static_assert(std::is_trivial<type>::value, "");
    };
};

template<typename T>
using Test = typename TestImpl<T>::Helper::type;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution with static_assert, but constraints work too:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace Private {
template<typename T>
struct Test {
   T x = 0;
};
}

template<typename T>
requires std::is_trivial<Private::Test<T>>::value
using Test = Private::Test<T>;

int main() {
    Test<int> test1;
    Test<float> test2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a destructor and put the static_assert there, at least with g++ 5.4 -std=c++11 this works.

Comment: It doesn't, for it's no longer trivial, even if you don't initialize `x`.

Comment: True, for *std::trivial* and *std::is_trivially_copyable* this is correct, for other use cases it should still be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

(moving from the comments)

You can add an intermediate class to keep the logic, and let your clients instantiate a derived one, which just contains the `static_assert`s

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct TestImpl {
    T x = 0; // make non-trivial
};

template<typename T>
struct Test : TestImpl<T> {
    static_assert(std::is_trivial<TestImpl<T>>::value, "");
    using TestImpl<T>::TestImpl; // inherit constructors
};
```

Comment: Fixed. It had a typo. It's `using TestImpl<T>::TestImpl;`, not `using TestImpl::TestImpl;`. Right?

Comment: Tnx. Can you comment on the solution I posted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's fully compliant but both [gcc trunk and clang trunk accept this](https://godbolt.org/z/61nK7WcWa):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr bool check_trivial()
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>);
    return std::is_trivial_v<T>;
}

template<typename T>
struct Test
{
   Test() noexcept(check_trivial<Test<T>>()) = default;

   T x;
};

struct nontrivial
{
    nontrivial(){}
};

int main() {
    // would like static assert failure, instead get 'incomplete type' error
    Test<int> test1;
    Test<nontrivial> test2;
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work when using the dtor instead of the ctor. YMMV.

This makes your type a non-aggregate though.

---

If your type has any mandatory member functions, you can put the `static_assert` in one of those function bodies. Member function bodies are evaluated after the end of the class definition, and therefore don't see an incomplete type.

For templates, the issue is that not all member functions are always instantiated. A `static_assert` in a non-instantiated member function won't fire. You need a call (any ODR-use actually) somewhere in the code to force instantiation.